# Keep CV on Cloud, after upload

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Keep uploaded CV on stack servers. to prevent upload again, for next Apply in [Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for your feedback.  We're already working on this feature and hope to ship fairly soon, after a bit more testing.

**Update:** This feature shipped two days ago.  Please let us know if you have any more feedback!

Comment: Out of curiosity - did this change between the career site and jobs site? I'm fairly sure (although most likely wrong) when I was playing with it - it retained my CV?

Comment: @JonClements I'm afraid I don't know -- I wasn't at Stack yet when Jobs became part of the main site.  From the code, it doesn't _look_ like the feature was ever implemented, but it's not impossible that it was removed at some point.